# SSRS DateAdd (Previous YR End,

Tags: reporting-services, dateadd

Hoping someone can help;

Im struggling a bit with the dateadd function on ssrs.

If for example I set my param. date as 30/4/16. And from that date I want to find:
1) previous yeard end (31-12-15)
2) previous 2 yr ends (31-12-14)

How do I go about it? I keep running into errors.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last day of the previous year like this:

```
=DateSerial(YEAR(Parameters!ReportParameter.Value) - 1, 12, 31)
```

So you are building a date by providing the year, month and day to use. You are just subtracting 1 year from the year of the parameter value. Similarly, subtract 2 for 2 years ago.